How can I download more than 3 photos that come in the same message?
I have tried to download 4 photos of the same message but I can't get it, here is the code I tried
This downloads only 1 image
        if (message.media) {
          const link = await handleMedia(message.media, userId);
          if (link.includes("pdf")) {
            filesRecibeds.add(link);
          } else {
            img_recibeds.push(link);
          }
        }

and this downloads the same photo 2 times, but not the 4 that are in the message, what am I doing wrong?
        if (message.groupedId) {
          const albumMessages = await client.getMessages(message.peerId, {
            ids: message.id, 
          });
  
          for (const mediaMessage of albumMessages) {
            if (mediaMessage.groupedId === message.groupedId) {
              if (mediaMessage.media) {
                const link = await handleMedia(mediaMessage.media, userId);
                if (link.includes("pdf")) {
                  filesRecibeds.add(link);
                } else {
                  img_recibeds.push(link);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

